# 0x Orderbook Explained

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to query the USDC/WETH orderbook for the best bid and ask. However, I don't think the response data makes much sense. There is a makerAmount and takerAmount. Does this mean that to interact with this limit order, I need to put up the price determined by the ratio of the 2 assets? This price/ratio seems to be very out of line with the prices I'm seeing on coinbase and other popular exchanges.

Am I missing anything? Or maybe I'm using the wrong API for my usecase?

Answer (score 0):

The price on a order is the ratio between the assets in units. Be in mind that `USDC` is a token with 6 decimals, and `WETH` a token with 18 decimals, so you need first to convert these values to their unit values. So for instance if you have an order with makerToken: `USDC` and takerToken: `WETH`, makerAmount: `2000 000000` and takerAmount `1 0000 0000 0000 0000 00`.

Converting this order to units:

```
MakerAmount: 2000 USDC

TakerAmount: 1 WETH
```

You are **making** a 2000 USDC to **take** for 1 WETH, which translates to 2000 WETH/USDC price.